# Help improve intuition solving equation with constraint with partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

The following problem is originally a standard problem in economics. I understand how to solve it, but would like to better understand how or why it works.

We have the following utility function
$u_i(c,l) = c - {l^2 \over 2}$
for individual $i$, where $c$ is consumption and $l$ is hours of labor. The individual faces the budget constraint $c = wL(1-\tau)$, where $w$ is the wage and $\tau$ is the tax rate. To solve for the *optimal labor supply*, as a function of $w$ and $\tau$, we substitute the budget constraint into the utility function. We get

$$u_i = wl(1-\tau) - {L^2 \over 2}$$

Finally, we take the partial derivative w.r.t l and solve for l.

$$l=w(1-\tau)$$

That is, the individual labor supply is a function of the tax rate. Higher tax, less labor supplied, and vice-versa.

What I don't quite understand is how this works. I guess it has something to do with the slope of a tangent, but I'm struggling with the intuition. My goal is to know how to do this intuitively so that I can apply this solution to other problems instead of just learning to do it mechanically.

Hope that my question is clear, let me know if it needs clarification.

Comment: When you take the derivative of $u_i$ with respect to $\ell$ and solve for when this equals $0$, you are looking for values of $\ell$ such that $u_i$ is maximal, when treating $u_i$ as a function just of $\ell$ alone. (In general points where the derivative vanish are critical points; here the point is indeed a maximum because the second derivative is negative). So when you calculate the derivative and solve for $\ell$ you are finding constraints such that $u_i$ is maximal.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense!